# Using substring within preg_replace

Tags: php, substring, preg-replace

I have a preg_replace:

`$text = preg_replace("/(\+?[\d-\(\)\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d)/", "$1", $text);`

I would like to use two substrings within this preg_replace. It should look something like this:

```
$text = preg_replace("/(\+?[\d-\(\)\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d)/", "<span id='number' data-last=substr($1, -5)>substr($1, 0, -5)<span>****<div class='showphone'>Show</div></span></span>", $text);
```

Notice the two substrings there. Obviously it's not a working example, but I am wondering if it's possible to make it work. Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use functions in double quotes like you can variables. You also can't use functions on the captured regex values, you should use `preg_replace_callback`. Something like this:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("/(\+?[\d-\(\)\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d)/", function($match) {
    return "<span id='number' data-last=" . substr($match[1], -5) . ">" . substr($match[1], 0, -5) . "<span>****<div class='showphone'>Show</div></span></span>";
}, $text);
```

should do it. With no example string though I couldn't test this.